# Uses of combining **kwargs and key word arguments in a method signature

Tags: python

Is there a use for combining **kwargs and keyword arguments in a method signature?

```
>>> def f(arg, kw=[123], *args, **kwargs): 
...  print arg
...  print kw
...  print args
...  print kwargs
... 
>>> f(5, 'a', 'b', 'c', kw=['abc'], kw2='def')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'kw'
```

It seems useless, but maybe someone has found a nice trick for it...

Comment: -1: Bad example.  See @Falmarri's answer.

Comment: If you read the question, I clearly don't have a good example.

Comment: @S.Lott A bad example is no reason for a downvote. If the OP fully and thoroughly understood the topic, he wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: So his question wasn't if there is a way to make something like his code work...to basically merge the arguments and the `kwargs` so that the `kwargs` are used as the defaults for the named arguments?  That's what I've shown up here wondering about.  I guess the green checkmark means he wasn't looking for what I am.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're assigning kw twice.

In this call `f(5, 'a', 'b', 'c', kw=['abc'], kw2='def')`, arg=5, kw='a', *args = ('b','c'), and then you're trying to assign kw again.

Answer (score 15):

In Python 3 you can have keyword-only arguments ([PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)).  With these, your function would look like this:

```
>>> def f(arg, *args, kw=[123], **kwargs): 
...  print(arg)
...  print(kw)
...  print(args)
...  print(kwargs)
>>> f(5, 'a', 'b', 'c', kw=['abc'], kw2='def')
5
('a', 'b', 'c')
['abc']
{'kw2': 'def'}
```

(Note that while I changed the order of the arguments I did not change the order of the `print`s.)

In Python 2 you can't have a keyword argument after a varargs argument, but in Python 3 you can, and it makes that argument keyword-only.

Also, be wary of [putting mutable objects as default parameters](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#default-parameter-values).

Comment: I don't know if this is what the author was looking for, but it's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you.