# How do you transparently pass arguments through to a function in python?

Tags: python

Specifically, when you have one function that calls another function, but the signature of the second function is unknown.

I know you can use *args and **kwargs for something similar to this, but I can't seem to get it quite right in a way that always works.

So for example, something like this almost works:

```
class Invoker():
  def __init__(self, call):
    self._call = call
  def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._call(*args, **kwargs)
```

..but if I write some tests for it I get this output:

```
1 -> 2  ('Hello')
1 -> 2  ((3, 'Hello'))
1 -> 2  ('Hello'), ({'left': 'right'})
1 -> 2  ((3,)), ({'value': 'Hello'})
call5() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'
call5() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'
```

from this code:

```
# Known argument list: works fine
def call(x, y, value=None):
  print("%d -> %d  (%r)" % (x, y, value))

invoker = Invoker(call)
invoker.call(1, 2, value="Hello")

# Unknown argument list with no kwargs: works fine
def call2(x, y, *args):
  print("%d -> %d  (%r)" % (x, y, args))

invoker = Invoker(call2)
invoker.call(1, 2, 3, "Hello")

# Unknown kwargs with default value: works fine
def call3(x, y, value=None, **kwargs):
  print("%d -> %d  (%r), (%r)" % (x, y, value, kwargs))

invoker = Invoker(call3)
invoker.call(1, 2, value="Hello", left="right")

# Unknown args and kwargs: works fine
def call4(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
  print("%d -> %d  (%r), (%r)" % (x, y, args, kwargs))

invoker = Invoker(call4)
invoker.call(1, 2, 3, value="Hello")

# Default value with unknown args: fails
try:
  def call5(x, y, value=None, *args):
    print("%d -> %d  (%r), (%r)" % (x, y, value, args))

  invoker = Invoker(call5)
  invoker.call(1, 2, 3, value="Hello")
except Exception, e:
  print(e)

# Default value with unknown args and kwargs: fails
try:
  def call6(x, y, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
    print("%d -> %d  (%r), (%r), (%r)" % (x, y, value, args, kwargs))

  invoker = Invoker(call5)
  invoker.call(1, 2, 3, value="Hello", left="right")
except Exception, e:
  print(e)
```

How can I write an method that calls another method that always works, when the signature of method to be called is unknown except at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't passing the arguments dynamically.  The problem is that you're trying to call the function with argument sets that aren't valid for that function.

For instance, look at `call5`, which you define with `def call5(x, y, value=None, *args)`.  The function has three arguments, one of which has a default, and then it has a `*args` catchall.

You then try to call this function with three positional arguments `(1, 2, 3)` and a keyword argument `value="Hello"`.  This is not a valid argument set for this function.  The fact that you're trying to do this in a dynamic way is just a red herring; it still won't work even if you try to literally do `call5(1, 2, 3 value="Hello")`, and `call5(1, 2, value="Hello", 3)` is a syntax error.  This function simply cannot accept three positional arguments plus a keyword-specified "value" argument.

You can define a function like your "invoker" that can call any function, but that doesn't change the fact that some combinations of positional and keyword arguments may not be valid for that function.  This isn't an artifact of your dynamic call structure, it's just how functions work: they have to be called with arguments that fit their signature.  If you pass too many arguments, the function will fail.  If the signature includes variable arguments, that gives you some leeway, but it doesn't change the fact that the function may still require a certain number of arguments, and if you pass less than that, it will fail.  You can't expect to pass any arbitrary tuple and dict of arguments and have it work for any function.

Or, put another way, you can write a generic invoker to call any function without the invoker machinery needing to know what the signature is, but whoever is using the invoker, and passing arguments to it, *does* have to know what the signature of the eventually-called function is.

Comment: Wow, you did an absolutely terrible job of explaining that, so I've posted another link as an alternative answer, but thank you, that is indeed what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why this doesn't work in python2 (and how to do it correctly in python3) are also better explained in this question:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4372346/uses-of-combining-kwargs-and-key-word-arguments-in-a-method-signature

Comment: That answer shows how to use keyword-only arguments in Python 3, but note that this doesn't change the fact that some argument sets won't be valid.  Making `value` a keyword-only argument would only change which argument sets are valid; it won't make them all valid.  For instance, if `value` is a keyword-only argument, then you could do `call5(1, 2, 3, value="Hello")`, but you could no longer do `call5(1, 2, "Hello", 3)`, as you can with your current definition.